Connection between 2 peers breaks when other 2 peers connect
I'm working on a feature for my personal project that includes a patient selects a particular doctor from a list to call them. The call goes to the doctor and they can accept or reject the it. When the doctor accepts, both are redirected to a room.
I'm using WebRTC with Springboot for this. The issue I'm facing is that the already established connection breaks between two people when the connection between other two people is established with the following error:
Room.jsx:83 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable
I'm really not sure why that's happening.
Here's how I've implemented the functionality:
PatientDashboard.jsx:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const PatientDashboard = () => {

     const [data, setData] = useState([]);

     const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

     const patientid = user.id;

     useEffect(() => {
          axios.get("http://localhost:9190/patient/doctors",{
               headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
               }
          })
               .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    // console.log(JSON.parse(res));
                    setData(res.data);
               })
               .catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
     }, []);


     const handleClick = (doctorid) => {
          // console.log("userid: ",user.id);
          // console.log("doctorid: ",doctorid);

          axios.post("http://localhost:9190/appointment/makeAppointment",
               {
                    "doctor": {
                         "id": doctorid
                    },
                    "patient": {
                         "id": patientid
                    }
               })
               .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
               })
               .catch((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
               })
     }




     return (
          <div>
               <div>Hi! {user.name}. This is your dashboard</div>

               {data.map((doctor, index) => {
                    return <div key={index} className='doctors'><h4>{doctor.name}</h4><Link to="/video-call-patient" onClick={() => { handleClick(doctor.id) }} state={{ caller: user.id, callee: doctor.id }}>Call</Link></div>

               })}

          </div>
     )
}

export default PatientDashboard;

VideoCallPatient.jsx: Could be thought of as waiting area (lobby)
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import Stomp from 'stompjs';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


const VideoCallPatient = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [remoteID, setRemoteId] = useState(location.state.callee);
  const [localID, setLocalId] = useState(location.state.caller);
  let peerConnection = useRef();
  let stompClient = useRef();

  const [testData, setTestData] = useState('');

  const navigate = useNavigate();


  useEffect(() => {

    var configuration = {
      iceServers: [{
        urls: [
          "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
          "stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478",
        ]
      }]
    };

    let peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    var conn = new SockJS("http://localhost:9190/socket");
    stompClient.current = new Stomp.over(conn);


    stompClient.current.connect({}, (frame) => {
      console.log(frame);
      stompClient.current.subscribe("/topic/testServer", (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
      })

      stompClient.current.subscribe("/user/" + localID + "/topic/acceptCall", (accept) => {
        const acceptBody = JSON.parse(accept.body);
        console.log(accept);
        navigate(`/room/${acceptBody.roomID}`, {state: {callee:remoteID, caller: localID}});
      })
   
      stompClient.current.send("/app/call", {}, JSON.stringify({
        "callTo": remoteID.toString(),
        "callFrom": localID.toString()
      }));

    });



  }, [])




  return (
    <div>
        Calling Doctor {remoteID}...
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoCallPatient;



DoctorDashboard.jsx: It's where the doctor gets the call

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import Stomp from 'stompjs';
import { useRef } from 'react';


const DoctorDashboard = () => {

  const [remoteID, setRemoteId] = useState('');
  const [localID, setLocalId] = useState(doctorId);
  const [incomingCall, setIncomingCall] = useState(false);
  const [roomID, setRoomID] = useState("");
  let stompClient = useRef();

  const navigate = useNavigate()


  const getAppointments = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:9190/doctor/appointments", { params: { doctorId: doctorId } })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setAppointments(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }


  const handleAcceptCall = () => {
    const newUuid = ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, (c) =>
      (c ^ (crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & (15 >> (c / 4)))).toString(16),
    );

    console.log(newUuid);

    setRoomID(newUuid);

    stompClient.current.send("/app/acceptCall", {}, JSON.stringify({
      "roomID": newUuid,
      "acceptedBy": localID.toString(),
      "initiatedBy": remoteID.toString()
    }));

    navigate(`/room/${newUuid}`, { state: { callee: remoteID, caller: localID } });


  }


  useEffect(() => {

    var configuration = {
      iceServers: [{
        urls: [
          "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
          "stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478",
        ]
      }]
    };

    let peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    var conn = new SockJS("http://localhost:9190/socket");
    stompClient.current = new Stomp.over(conn);


    stompClient.current.connect({}, (frame) => {

      stompClient.current.subscribe("/user/" + localID + "/topic/call", (call) => {
        console.log("call from: " + call.body);
        console.log("remote id: " + call.body);

        setRemoteId(call.body);

        setIncomingCall(true);

        peerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = async (event) => {
          await peerConnection.createOffer().then(async (description) => {
            await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description);
            console.log("negotiation setting description: ", peerConnection.localDescription);
            stompClient.current.send("/app/offer", {}, JSON.stringify({
              "toUser": call.body.toString(),
              "fromUser": doctorId.toString(),
              "offer": JSON.stringify(description)
            }));
          })
        }

      })

    })



  }, [])





  return (
    <div>
      <div>Hi! {user["name"]}. This is your dashboard</div>
      
      <div>

        {
          incomingCall
            ?
            <div style={{ position: 'fixed', width: "100%", height: "100%", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,0,0.9)", backdropFilter: blur("10px"), zIndex: "2", top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, left: 0 }}>
              <h4 style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                Patient {remoteID} is calling you
              </h4>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-evenly", width: "20%" }}>
                <button style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }} onClick={handleAcceptCall}>Accept</button>
                <button style={{ backgroundColor: "Red" }}>Reject</button>
              </div>

            </div>
            :
            <></>

        }

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DoctorDashboard;


Room.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import Stomp from 'stompjs';




const Room = () => {
     const location = useLocation();

     console.log(location)

     let stompClient = useRef();

     let localVideoRef = useRef();
     let remoteVideoRef = useRef();
     const [remoteID, setRemoteId] = useState(location.state.callee);
     const [localID, setLocalId] = useState(location.state.caller);


     useEffect(() => {

          var configuration = {
               iceServers: [{
                    urls: [
                         "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
                         "stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478",
                    ]
               }]
          };

          let peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
          var conn = new SockJS("http://localhost:9190/socket");
          stompClient.current = new Stomp.over(conn);


          stompClient.current.connect({}, (frame) => {

               stompClient.current.subscribe("/user/" + localID + "/topic/offer", async (offer) => {
                    console.log("offer: ", JSON.parse(offer.body));
                    const offerData = JSON.parse(offer.body);
                    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(offerData.offer));

                    console.log("setting remote description: ", peerConnection.remoteDescription);

                    peerConnection.createAnswer().then(async (description) => {
                         await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description);
                         console.log("setting description: ", peerConnection.localDescription);
                         stompClient.current.send("/app/answer", {}, JSON.stringify({
                              "toUser": offerData.fromUser.toString(),
                              "fromUser": offerData.toUser.toString(),
                              "answer": JSON.stringify(description)
                         }));
                    })
               })   

               stompClient.current.subscribe("/user/" + localID + "/topic/candidate", async (answer) => {
                    // console.log("candidate: ", JSON.parse(answer.body));
                    const candidateData = JSON.parse(answer.body);

                    console.log("candidate: ", candidateData);

                    const candidate = JSON.parse(candidateData.candidate);
                    console.log(candidate);
                    console.log("remote description: ", peerConnection.remoteDescription);
                    console.log("local description: ", peerConnection.localDescription);
                    if (candidate && peerConnection && peerConnection.remoteDescription.type)
                         await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);

               })

               stompClient.current.subscribe("/user/" + localID + "/topic/answer", async (answer) => {

                    console.log("negotiation answer: ", answer.body);

                    const answerData = JSON.parse(answer.body);

                    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(answerData.answer));
                    console.log("negotiation remote description: ", peerConnection.remoteDescription);


               });

               peerConnection.createOffer().then(async (description) => {
                    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description);
                    console.log("setting description: ", description);
                    stompClient.current.send("/app/offer", {}, JSON.stringify({
                         "toUser": remoteID.toString(),
                         "fromUser": localID.toString(),
                         "offer": JSON.stringify(description)
                    }))
               })

               peerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = async (event) => {
                    await peerConnection.createOffer().then(async (description) => {
                         await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description);
                         console.log("negotiation setting description: ", peerConnection.localDescription);
                         stompClient.current.send("/app/offer", {}, JSON.stringify({
                              "toUser": remoteID.toString(),
                              "fromUser": localID.toString(),
                              "offer": JSON.stringify(description)
                         }));
                    })
               }


               peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
                    console.log(event);
                    if (event.candidate) {
                         stompClient.current.send("/app/candidate", {}, JSON.stringify({
                              "toUser": remoteID.toString(),
                              "fromUser": localID.toString(),
                              "candidate": JSON.stringify(event.candidate)
                         }))
                    }
               }

               peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
                    console.log("remote streams: ", event.streams);
                    remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = event.streams[0];
               }

               navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: true,
                    audio: true
               }).then((stream) => {
                    localVideoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
                    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                         peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
                    });
               })

          })



     }, [])





     return (

          <div>
               <video ref={localVideoRef} autoPlay muted />
               <video ref={remoteVideoRef} autoPlay />
          </div>
     )
}

export default Room


I've been working on webrtc for quite some days now. It would be highly appreciable if somebody could let me know what is it that I'm missing.
Thanks
